# Is the P vs. NP question formally independent?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, computational-complexity, computability

This question was considered some years ago by Scott Aaronson
http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/pnp.pdf
and after some research I believe the answer is yes.  The two main references with the technical details are

- http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0204037
- https://ecommons.cornell.edu/handle/1813/6063

There are primitive recursive oracles *A* and *B* such that $P^A=NP^A$ and $P^B\ne NP^B$.

There is a p.r. oracle $H^*$ such that
$$x\in H^*$$
if and only if
$$\bigg(F[\le x](E^*\rightarrow \lnot R^*)\land\lnot F[\le x](E^*\rightarrow R^*)\land x\in A \bigg)\\ \lor \\ \bigg(F[\le x](E^*\rightarrow R^*)\land\lnot F[\le x](E^*\rightarrow \lnot R^*)\land x\in B\bigg)$$
where by definition
$$ Q:\leftrightarrow P=NP \\ R^*:\leftrightarrow P^{H^*}=NP^{H^*}
\\ E^*:\leftrightarrow (R^*\leftrightarrow Q)$$
and "$F[\le x]S$" denotes the existence of a valid proof with Gödel number not exceeding *x* for the statement *S* in the formal system *F*, which is here understood to be any system containing sufficient arithmetic to acceptably enumerate proofs.

The existence of $H^*$ is provable following Hartmanis and Hopcroft.

$E^*$ is ***relatively consistent*** to *F*: if $F[<\infty]\lnot E^*$ then *F* itself is inconsistent because it proves its own consistency.  Furthermore we can prove that if $F[<\infty]Q$ then $F[<\infty](E^*\rightarrow R^*)$ and if $F[<\infty]\lnot Q$ then $F[<\infty](E^*\rightarrow \lnot R^*)$.

Hence **if $F[<\infty]P=NP$ or $F[<\infty]P\ne NP$, then there is a proof of a proof of a contradiction in *F*.**

Related: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2016/11/friday_squid_bl_551.html#c6737756
https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2016/09/amtrak_security_1.html#c6735169

**EDIT:** I have expanded this question into a whole paper, available at the following URLs, and I am still looking for more detailed answers, as my paper lacks a firm conclusion.

- https://www.docdroid.net/OvhoFHI/pnp.pdf.html
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ahqmM-Tg52ZVVRWVoteTVtTWc

Comment: Could you please emphasize the specific question you are asking? It is not clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are arguing that P=NP is independent of any consistent theory $F$ containing Peano arithmetic.  If so, the proof cannot be correct since it would apply to $F=PA + "\!\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}\!"$ (or, for that matter, to $F=PA+ "\!\mathrm{P}\ne \mathrm{NP}\!"),$ so that that P=NP would be independent of those theories too, which clearly isn't true.

If you're really interested in pursuing this, you need to specify in advance the theory that you're trying to prove P=NP independent of (PA, ZFC, whatever).  No statement is going to be independent of *every* theory (or every sufficiently strong theory).

Comment: The proof also doesn't seem to use anything about P or NP. As a separate example, we know that IP = PSPACE, but there are oracles $A$ and $B$  relative to which IP($A$) is not equal to PSPACE($A$) while IP($B$) is equal to PSPACE($B$).  So it is not clear what about the proof sketched above would go wrong if we used these $A$ and $B$, and IP and PSPACE - but we can prove that unrelativized IP and PSPACE are equal to each other.  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_(complexity) and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000005800844

Comment: Bad reduction.  We don't even know whether or not PA==PA+"P==NP" or PA==PA+"P!=NP"; I am saying that *if either of these is true,* then PA|-(PA|-(PA|-$\bot$)).